# Remove 7 characters from every row

Tags: python

How am I supposed to do so this code removes last 7 characters from each row?

```
string = """
    "bleach": 1.0,
    "ducttape": 1.0,
"""
result = string[:-7]
print(result)
```

Comment: you want to collect/parse each words like, bleach, ducttape etc?

Comment: Try `for row in string.split('\n'): ...`

Comment: try doing L = string.split("\n") and creating a new list and appending each time L[i][-5:-7] to the new list; note : -4 for the 4 spaces before each word and the "

Answer (score 2):

```
string = """
    "bleach": 1.0,
    "ducttape": 1.0,
"""
for row in string.split('\n'):
    result = row[:-6]
    result=result+","
    print(result)
```

Comment: Please do not submit code only answers. Explain the code. Thanks!

Comment: its not that hard to be explained. pretty much self explanatory even for beginners. nevertheless, the golden rule of programming says, write a code in such that it doesn't need explanation.

Comment: @kishore: That rule would be more for professional programmers — so doesn't really apply here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @martineu `doesnt apply here` is fine, in context of this question, but not `here on sof` what do you mean pros are not here on sof? . you yourself seem to a professional. 